# time data '2017-09-05 18:32:38.159+00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, format, valueerror

ValueError: time data '2017-09-05 18:32:38.159+00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
How can I fit a '+00'?

Comment: Hey, did my answer help clear this up. Please mark as correct if so.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the `%f`. It should be zero padded on the left.

> %f Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left. 000000

Also as stated in the comment below `%z` expects the format `+0000` or `-0000`

> %z UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the the object is naive).

For example the following works:

```
from time import strptime

string = strptime('2017-09-05 18:32:38.00159+0000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

http://strftime.org/

Comment: Also, `%z` matches a UTC offset of the form `+HHMM` or `-HHMM`. So `+00` needs to be changed to something like `+0000`.  (e.g. `datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-09-05 18:32:38.159000+0000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')`).

Comment: I thought it might pick up the `+00` if everything else was in the right place. I take it that it doesn't? Also I'm not sure what "empty string if the the object is naive" means.

Comment: It has to be exactly of the form `+HHMM` or `-HHMM`. For more flexible datetime string parsing, the OP could use [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Then `dateutil.parser.parse('2017-09-05 18:32:38.159+00')` would work.

Comment: Yes I just tested it it only works with all digits, I have seen `+00` on time strings before, that's why I wasn't sure.